# pandas to_latex() escapes mathmode

Tags: python, pandas, latex

[pandas to_latex() methode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html) seems to be a convenient way to convert bigger tabulars into into latex code. However, writing math mode, the `$` seems to get escaped.

An example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

table=np.asarray([['$x^2$',3]])
df=pd.DataFrame(table[:,1], columns=['value'], index=table[:,0])
print(df.to_latex(encoding='utf-8'))
```

output:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
{} & value \\
\midrule
\$x\textasciicircum2\$ &     3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the method's escape parameter is set to True by default. You can change it to False:

```
print(df.to_latex(encoding='utf-8', escape=False))

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
{} & value \\
\midrule
$x^2$ &     3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```