# Export a pd.DataFrame with latex labels to latex

Tags: pandas, latex

I've got a table that can be reconstructed with the following code

```
results = [(4.898, 6.345, 0.0564),
           (5.000, 6.250, 0.0637)]
df = pd.DataFrame(results,
                  columns=["$mu$","$\sigma^2$","$\widetilde{\mu_3}$"],
                  index=["$w_1$","$w_2$"])
```

When I export it it with  `df.to_latex("myDirectory/myTable.tex")` and read it into latex `\input{./myDirectory/myTable}` the resulting table looks like

```
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
    \toprule
    {} &   \$mu\$ &  \$\textbackslash sigma\textasciicircum 2\$ &  \$\textbackslash widetilde\{\textbackslash mu\_3\}\$ \\
    \midrule
    \$w\_1\$ &  4.899 &       6.345 &                0.056 \\
    \$w\_2\$ &  5.000 &       6.250 &                0.064 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

when for it render properly it should

```
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
      \toprule
      {} &     $\mu$ &   $ \sigma^2$ &   $\widetilde{\mu_3}$ \\
      \midrule
      $w_1$ &  4.899 &  6.345 &  0.056 \\
      $w_2$ &  5.000 &  6.250 &  0.064 \\
      \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Is there an easy fix to this or does Pandas not support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, adding `escape=False` in `to_latex()` fixed it for me. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44261383/9371695). Writing my table looks like this:

```py
df.to_latex(
    buf="table.tex",
    escape=False,
)
```

Comment: I haven't tested this again but I'm sure this will the solution the next time I need to do this