# Using latex commands in pandas dataframe, then converting it to latex table

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I have a pandas dataframe, say

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3), columns = ['$\epsilon$','$ \delta$', '$\gamma$'])
df.iloc[0,2] = '$\textbf{' + str(df.iloc[0,2]) + '}$'
df.iloc[1,2] = '$\textbf{' + str(df.iloc[1,2]) + '}$'
```

In Jupyter Notebook, `df` is displayed very nice: columns with greek letters, and the numbers 2 and 5 are bold. In particular, I want to make the maximum of each row bold (and/or highlight it with a colored background).

However when I use `print(df.to_latex())` and copy it to latex, the resulting table contains actual dollar symbols and backslashes.

How can I solve this problem? Do I have to manually change the codes in latex?

Comment: if you know latex then first you could open your latex file in editor and see if it use `$` in correct way. OR maybe you should generate it without `$`

Comment: I had the same issue. It is escaping the special symbols. You can do `df.to_latex(escape=False)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas to\_latex() escapes mathmode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260547/pandas-to-latex-escapes-mathmode)